# Why do I have to call base.OnAuthorization(filterContext)

Tags: asp.net, authorization, asp.net-web-api

I've seen plenty of guides where implementation of custom authorization filter involves calling base.OnAuthorization(filterContext) as final step. I have my own custom authorization filter and it works perfectly without above mentioned. However, when I add call to base.OnAuthorization(filterContext), my WebAPI service returns 401, even though all checks passed successfully.

1) Why do I have to call base.OnAuthorization?
2) How come it returns 401 on it's own?

EDIT: I'm thinking it has to do with default Membership and Role providers. Since I'm sort of skipping those, could that be the reason?

As soon as I call base.OnAuthorization, my Response becomes 401.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to call that if you handle everything yourself.

But if you do, authorization logic will pull the user (`IPrincipal.Identity`) out of `Thread.CurrentPrincipal` and will deny authorization (401) if one of the following conditions is met:

- `IPrincipal` is null
- `IPrincipal.Identity` is not authenticated
- `IPrincipal.Identity` is authenticated but is not in the authorized
  group of users, or if the user is not in any of the authorized roles 
  (specified on the attribute)